# ArrayAdapter() : no suitable constructor found

Tags: java, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I am Starting with Android programming. I can't compile my program as I get the following error :

`Error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter()`

Here is my personnal adapter:

```
public class StationListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Station> {

    private ArrayList<Station> stations;
    private Context context;
    private int resource;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    //Constructor - args : (context, resourceId, ArrayList<MyClass>)
    public StationListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Station> stations) {

        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.stations = stations;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Here is the part of the frament that instance the adapter:

```
public void onArrayListReady(ArrayList<Station> stations) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_list_textview);
    ListView listView = (ListView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_list_stations_list);
    adapter = new StationListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_list_row, stations);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: You're not calling `super` in your adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to call a super constructor from your constructor in order to properly initialize your adapter.

Comment: Thanks very much ! That was it. 
It may sound like a stupid question but how could I know that I had to create a construction and calling the parent constructor in it ?
(Beginner in Java and Android)

Comment: The only stupid question is an unasked question.  You should assume that the class from which you are extending needs to be initialized as well.  As such, it's good practice to always call the super constructor unless you are intentionally preventing the super constructor call.

Comment: That, I won't fotget. Thanks again.